# How can I adjust my image position after I change the anchor point? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, pinch, anchorpoint

I am using `UIGestureRecognizer` to make the pinch action and I need to change the anchor point to resize to the correct point of my `UIImage`. After I change the anchor point, the image moves a little bit, and I need to put it back to the origin. Here is what i am doing:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    imageThinkCreatively.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.6, 0.7)
    imageThinkCreatively.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0, 200.0)
    imageThinkCreatively.layoutIfNeeded()
}
@IBAction func scaleImage(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    sender.view!.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sender.view!.transform, sender.scale, sender.scale)
    sender.scale = 1

 }
```

But the image does not change the origin or the size... What am i doing wrong?